# error in method-override installation

Tags: node.js

i am having this error below

```
Error: Cannot find module 'method-override'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/web/admin_and_store_panel/server.js:4:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

even though i have install

> npm install method-override

Comment: Please show your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check in the `node_modules` folder if you have method-override folder. If it's not there it probably didn't get installed properly.

You could try removing and reinstalling it again by running these commands

1. `rm -rf node_modules/`  //removes node modules
2. `rm -rf package-lock.json` // removes package-lock.json file
3. `npm i --save method-override` // reinstalls package and saves in package.json

Answer (score 1):

You have to require the package as below:

```
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
```

`methodOverride` should be the variable as the index file of method-override module exports it as `methodOverride`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because either it's not installed properly or it's not present in the **node-modules** folder. You could reinstall it by following the below steps:

1. Delete the **package-lock.json** folder.
2. Execute this command on terminal or windows command line `npm install --save method-override`

Answer (score 0):

Just run this on cmd : npm install --save method-override

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).